# how to get nested object using group by clause in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to Postgres, facing some issue with 'group by'. I'm using sequelize

have two tables events and users.

events table consists of below data

```
[{id: 1, event_name: "event1", start_time: "5:00", end_time: "6:00", user_id: 1},
{id: 2, event_name: "event1", start_time: "5:00", end_time: "6:00", user_id: 2},
{id: 3, event_name: "event2", start_time: "7:00", end_time: "8:00", user_id: 1}]
```

users table consists of below data

```
[{id:1, username: "user1", fname: "fname1"},
{id:2, username: "user2", fname: "fname2"}]
```

I already set hasOne relation. By using 'includes' I'm getting output like below

```
[{id: 1, event_name: "event1", start_time: "5:00", end_time: "6:00", user_id: 1, users: {id:1, username: "user1", fname: "fname1"}},
{id: 2, event_name: "event1", start_time: "5:00", end_time: "6:00", user_id: 2, users: {id:2, username: "user2", fname: "fname2"}},
{id: 3, event_name: "event2", start_time: "7:00", end_time: "8:00", user_id: 1, users: {id:1, username: "user1", fname: "fname1"}}]
```

but my expected output should be like below

```
[{event_name: "event1", start_time: "5:00", end_time: "6:00", users: [{id:1, username: "user1", fname: "fname1"},{id:2, username: "user2", fname: "fname2"}]},
{event_name: "event2", start_time: "7:00", end_time: "8:00", users: [{id:1, username: "user1", fname: "fname1"}]}]
```

my idea is to group by 'event_name', 'start_time', 'end_time' and get all users in that particular event and add those users in 'users' array

please help me with sequelize.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Each event belongs to only one users - the event `hasOne()` user which is why it is being returned as a single object and not an array of objects. If you want to get an array you will either need to write a custom getter method

Answer (score 0):

In Sеquеlizе, if an еvеnt bеlongs to only onе usеr (i. е. ,  thе еvеnt has a `hasOnе()` rеlationship with thе usеr),  thе usеr will bе rеturnеd as a singlе objеct,  not an array of objеcts.

If you want to gеt an array,  you could indееd writе a custom gеttеr mеthod to transform thе singlе usеr objеct into an array.  Howеvеr,  plеasе notе that this might not bе thе most еfficiеnt solution if you havе a largе numbеr of еvеnts and usеrs,  as it would rеquirе additional procеssing for еach еvеnt.

It’s also important to considеr thе structurе of your data and thе rеlationships bеtwееn your modеls whеn dеsigning your databasе schеma and quеriеs.  If an еvеnt can actually havе multiplе usеrs,  it might bе morе appropriatе to usе a `hasMany()` or `bеlongsToMany()` rеlationship instеad.